# javascript, declare associative array of regex expressions

Tags: javascript

How to declare associative array of regex?
This is not working

```
var Validators = {

    url : /^http(s?)://((\w+\.)?\w+\.\w+|((2[0-5]{2}|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(2[0-5]{2}|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}))(/)?$/gm   

};
```

EDITED: Now working!

This will be valid in JS (like @ operator in C#)

```
url : `/^http(s?)://((\w+\.)?\w+\.\w+|((2[0-5]{2}|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(2[0-5]{2}|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}))(/)?$/gm`
```

However, will still not work due to double escape, one in JS and other in Regex. If expression is small, perhaps naked eye can manually escape for both JS and Regex. My brain just can't :)

In order to **use strings as tested** on regex101.com for example, all required strings should be declared as 'row' like this:

```
var exp = String.raw`^(http(s?):\/\/)?(((www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)|(\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b))(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\s\.\/\?\%\#\&\=]*)?$`;



var strings = [
    String.raw`http://www.goo gle.com`,
    String.raw`http://www.google.com`,
    ];
```

Comment: don't use `g`. that makes them sticky.

Comment: Well your code is throwing a syntax error, fix your regex so it doesn't have a syntax error and try again

Comment: To help you troubleshoot that syntax error, paste your regular expression (only the part between the `/` `/`, not including the slashes) into https://regex101.com/ and then take note of the error messages and the red highlights. They will show you exactly what to fix.

Comment: *"This is not working"* is not a useful problem description. We don't know *how* you expect it to "work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with `new RegExp()` and escape slashes

```
var Validators = {

    url : new RegExp( /^http(s?):\/\/((\w+\.)?\w+\.\w+|((2[0-5]{2}|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(2[0-5]{2}|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}))(\/)?$/gm ) 

};
```

Comment: I accepted your answer and vote because you gave me the clue :) can be escaped with `` in JS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex has forward slashes in it. This symbol needs to be escaped because it is supposed to indicate the start and end of the expression. Try `\/`.

Comment: Thanks. I tested and indeed, regex is broken. I just took from another StackOverflow.. hmm... this means that some people should test their code before post as valid answers.